# Linux - troubleshooting the "too many open files" error

Tags: linux, bash

On RHEL, I have the "too many open files" error. I'd like to reproduce it so that I understand what exactly is causing it.

- `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` gives the max open files at OS-level. `./file-nr` gives the number of current open files
- `sudo lsof | wc -l` is another way to look at the amount of current open files alhough it contains duplicated values as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36841).
- `ulimit -n` is the max open files per process (for me 1024)
- `sudo lsof -p <PID> | wc -l` gives the `lsof` version of the number of open files for a current process.

I would be after a `bash` solution if possible, that creates a process that blows up the `ulimit -n` just by opening dummy files. Potentially, I'd like to use several of those test processes to blow up the OS limit as well.

Also how can I properly kill such processes? Thanks

This will allow me to check exactly what limit is reached (`file-max` or `lsof...`) and to experiment on what kind of operations are causing it.

Comment: That said, to provide comments that might help with a few of the narrower issues you raised: In _most_ cases, this error is the per-process table. `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` is the easiest way to view that table for a given PID; there's no reason to involve `lsof` when you know the PID.

Comment: And with a new enough version of bash, `exec {new_fd}>/dev/null` will open a new handle on `/dev/null` and store the FD for that handle in the variable `new_fd`. Repeat as many times as you want if your goal is to use FDs (though I don't know why such a "probe" would be of any use).

Comment: @Charles These 3 questions are absolutely related and on the same topic. I could reformulate this using only 1 question.

Comment: They're _related_, sure, but that doesn't make them the same question. Curation is a community responsibility; it's not proper behavior to leave it undone simply by request.

Comment: Anyhow, if the only thing you really want to know is how to write bash code that goes up to the limit, that's narrow and specific enough to be on-topic, and I'm happy to make an answer of my comment above.

Comment: here you go, one question, "how can I do this and close it thereafter?". Hope that fits in your rules

Comment: Agreed, this is now clear and narrowly-scoped.

Comment: ...well, it _was_ clearly scoped until you changed the title back. Now it's back to being broad (there are _lots_ of questions in our knowledgebase already about troubleshooting too-many-open-files whose answers have no relevance to you here -- often they're about language- or library-specific leaks, f/e).

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[1-3].*|4.0.*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.1 or newer required" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

[[ $1 ]] || { echo "Usage: $0 number-of-files" >&2; exit 1; }

echo "Running as process $$" >&2
for ((i=0; i<$1; i++)); do
  exec {fd_num}>/dev/null || {
    echo "Error on iteration $((i+1))" >&2
    break
  }
done

# if started from a TTY, let user press enter to exit
# otherwise (f/e, if run with </dev/null), keep running until we're killed
if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
  read -p "Press enter to exit this process:" _
else
  while :; do sleep 600 || exit; done
fi
```

If this outputs `Running as process 26941`, you can then `ls -l /proc/26941/fd` to see that the file descriptors are genuinely in use (and count them, if you choose).

Comment: BTW, note that your script will always inherit at least stdin, stdout and stderr on startup (and will generally have another FD open reading the source code to the script itself, plus one for the bash executable and another for each library that executable uses; so the number that can be opened will be somewhat less than the limit).

Comment: When I ran your script with arg=10000, got "Error on iteration 1014". The maximum is 1013, plus 4 (0,1,2,255), that makes 1017. My `ulimit -a` shows `open files (-n) 1024`. How can we explain this gap of 7 ?

Comment: @Philippe, `ls -l /proc/$PID/fd` (for the individual process's PID) and _see_ what the set of actually-open FDs are.

Comment: @Philippe, ...that said, as I mentioned above, bash itself will often have shared libraries open (glibc &c).

Answer (score 1):

You could create 2000 file descriptors to test the `ulimit`, if the number set is lower than 2000.

Give a try to this:

```
inc=1
while [ $inc -lt 2000 ] ; do
  exec {file_descriptor}>/tmp/dummy_file_$inc.txt
  inc=$((inc+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a simple Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Open maximum number per session file descriptors
use strict;
use warnings;
my $secs = shift || 10;
my @fh;
while (1) {
    my $fh;
    open( $fh, ">", "/dev/null" ) or last;
    push( @fh, $fh );
}
print $!, " [ ", scalar @fh, " ]\n";
sleep $secs;
1;
```

The script can be run with one optional argument denoting the time to sleep after the `ulimit` exhaustion. The default wait time is 10 seconds.

On a system with a `ulimit` of 1024:

```
Too many open files [ 1021 ]
```

Upon exhaustion of the `ulimit`, the operating system reason for the `open` failure is returned noting the number of descriptors created. As every process has three standard file descriptors, the limit is reached is `ulimit -3`.